# And condition in Case Statement IN SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, dynamic-sql

I have the below sql..@FeeType is a parameter of the stored procedure..I am getting a error when I call the below logic..If I remove the and condition and make the logic just

```
WHEN ''ItemDesc'' THEN ''Item Description1''
```

then the logic works fine..Can someone please have a look and let me know what I am doing wrong here.

```
SELECT @FIELDS = (COALESCE(@FIELDS, '' '','''') + ''<td style='' + 
                  ''"border:1px solid   black;color:white">'' +
                  (CASE name 
                  WHEN ''ItemDesc'' and '+ @FeeType +' = ''1'' THEN ''Item Description1''
                  WHEN ''ItemDesc'' and '+ @FeeType +' = ''2'' THEN ''Item Description2''
                  WHEN ''Units'' THEN ''Units'' 
                  WHEN ''Rate'' THEN ''Rate''
                  WHEN ''Frequency'' THEN ''Frequency''
                  WHEN ''Annual'' THEN ''Annual''
                  WHEN ''BasedOn'' THEN ''Based On'' ELSE ''Misc'' END) +  ''</td>'' 
                 )

FROM tempdb.sys.Columns
WHERE object_id=object_id(''tempdb..#FeesCalculation'')
AND name not like ''CustColHTML_ID'' 
AND name not like ''ItemID''
```

Thanks

Comment: Why have you used two single quotes twice everywhere ? Is this a dynamic query ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention it..Yes it is

Comment: can you post the full query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `CASE` has two different possible syntaxes:

1. `CASE variable WHEN value1 THEN expression2 WHEN value2 THEN expression2 [...] ELSE expression3 END`
2. `CASE WHEN condition1 THEN expression1 ELSE expression2 END`

The first one is when you simply need to compare the value. If you need any more complex logic you should probably use the second option. In your case it seems you can use a combination of two of the first syntax.

So, what you need to do is:

```
SELECT @FIELDS = (COALESCE(@FIELDS, '' '','''') + ''<td style='' + 
                  ''"border:1px solid   black;color:white">'' +
                  (CASE name 
                  WHEN ''ItemDesc'' THEN CASE @FeeType WHEN ''1'' THEN ''Item Description1'' WHEN ''2'' THEN ''Item Description2'' END
                  WHEN ''Units'' THEN ''Units'' 
                  WHEN ''Rate'' THEN ''Rate''
                  WHEN ''Frequency'' THEN ''Frequency''
                  WHEN ''Annual'' THEN ''Annual''
                  WHEN ''BasedOn'' THEN ''Based On'' ELSE ''Misc'' END) +  ''</td>'' 
                 )
```

You will probably need to fix the concatenation and quotes, I removed them for simplicity.